# ¿Como acceder a un metodo de una subclase desde un ArrayList de la superclase?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public class SeleccionFutbol{

protected int carnetIdent;
protected String nombre;
protected String apellidos;
protected int edad;

public SeleccionFutbol(int id, String n, String a, int edad){
  carnetIdent =   id;
  nombre      =    n;
  apellidos   =    a;
  this.edad   = edad;
   }
    //getters y setters
}
```

y las subclase:

```
public class Entrenador extends SeleccionFutbol{
private String codEntrenador;

public Entrenador(int id, String n, String a, int edad, String cod){
 super(id,n,a,edad);
 codEntrenador = cod;
  }
  //getters y setters
}
```

Y tengo un ArrayList del tipo SeleccionFutbol, del cual debo mostrar los datos del entrenador, lo cual hice asi:

```
System.out.println("El entrenador que dirigira el partido es: ");
    for(SeleccionFutbol s : integrantes){
        if(s instanceof Entrenador){
        System.out.println(s.getNombre() + " "+ s.getApellido() + ",edad: " + getEdad());
      }
    }
```

Pero no se como mostrar el codigo del entrenador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convierte `s` a `Entrenador` para poder acceder al codigo del entrenador:

```
System.out.println("El entrenador que dirigira el partido es: ");
for(SeleccionFutbol s : integrantes){
    if(s instanceof Entrenador){

    // convertimos s en Entregador
    Entrenador en = (Entrenador)s;

    // accedemos las propiedades de en
    System.out.println(en.getCodEntregador())
    System.out.println(s.getNombre() + " "+ s.getApellido() + ",edad: " + getEdad());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Las clases hijas heredan los métodos de la clase padre, por lo que si tienes los getters en Entrenador con hacer

```
s.getId();
```

lo obtendras

Una cosa importante y una opinión no creo que Selección de Futbol sea un hijo de la clase Entrenador, más bien yo pensaría en que Entrenador es un atributo de Selección de fútbol.

Échale un ojo una vez más a la herencia

Comment: Use herencia por que tengo 2 otras subclases  que heredan de SeleccionFutbol.